# PCI system error (SERR) for reason b1 on cpu 0

Tags: boot, intel-pentium, puppylinux, slax

I am trying to boot the SLAX OS using pen-drive but every time i boot it shows this error message "pci system error serr for reason b1 on cpu 0" and after this it says "Linux Kernel Dazed and Confused". I am trying to install it on HP Desktop which have Pentium 4 with 1 GB of RAM.

Also i tried with another light weight os like Slacko Puppy but again boot stucks at "Recognizing  Optical Devices "
And with Slitaz it stops at "Configuring Loop Back".

Comment: It seems there's an issue with your system's SATA interface. On a machine this old, it's possible the chipset is failing.